# Javascript random content into 3 divs from 5 sources without duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 container divs and 5 content divs. Each time the page loads, I want to randomly insert a single content div into each of the 3 container divs, without duplicating any of the content divs (each container div needs to have a unique content div).

```
<!--Container Divs-->
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>

<!--Content Divs-->
<div style="display:none">
 <div class="source one">Contents of source 1</div>
 <div class="source two">Contents of source 2</div>
 <div class="source three">Contents of source 3</div>
 <div class="source four">Contents of source 4</div>
 <div class="source five">Contents of source 5</div>
</div>
```

I'm using WordPress so jQuery is already loaded if that makes it easier. Thanks for the help. I think it will involve an appendHTML after a javascript routine selects a random div that hasn't already been selected.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific, because it's unclear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I thought I was overly specific, lol. What are you missing?

Answer (score 1):

Random sort the content source elements then loop through the display container elements and insert content with same index

```js
var $content = $('.source').sort(function() {
  return Math.random() - .5;
})

$('#one, #two, #three').append(function(i) {
  return $content[i];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Container Divs-->
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>

<!--Content Divs-->
<div style="display:none">
  <div class="source one">Contents of source 1</div>
  <div class="source two">Contents of source 2</div>
  <div class="source three">Contents of source 3</div>
  <div class="source four">Contents of source 4</div>
  <div class="source five">Contents of source 5</div>
</div>
```